# Find and move QuickTime files

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, terminal.app

I have a serious number of QuickTime files in a series of deeply nested folders (by date, by provider) on a connected server.

Is there an easy command that will both find the file (I know the exact name and there will be no duplicates) and then copy it to a predetermined folder on the same server? Or even better, move it to that predetermined folder rather than copy it?

I work with FileMaker from which I can send the terminal commands so I can automate this process for hundreds of files, but I rarely use the terminal and could use this very basic help.

Comment: Please [edit] and give your question a meaningful title. Telling us your OS in the title is useless information.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` and `mv`.

```
find / -name "<yourfilename>" -exec mv "{}" "<the destination folder>" \; -print
```

Comment: Thank you.  Is there a way to limit the volumes searched?  I have a lot of connected volumes and I only need to search one of them.

Comment: You can do `find /Users` if you want, instead of `/`, so as to avoid system folders and `/Volumes`.